# Extension of Action in Algebraic Groups

Tags: algebraic-groups, abelian-varieties

[image]

I am reading the proof in Borel's book, "Linear Algebraic Groups" of the fact if $G$ is connected affine group of dimension one, then it is either $\mathbb{G}_a$ or $\mathbb{G}_m$. In the proof it is written the translation extends uniquely to $\overline{G}$. Is this extension only as action of abstract groups or also as algebraic groups? What is the reason?

Comment: Just a comment - presumably you do not have access to (AG. 18.5 (*))?

Comment: @peterag no I don't have, one professor gave me only this part since I asked about the result

Comment: This has been crossposted to MO [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/435087/extension-of-action-in-algebraic-group).

Comment: The action of $$ on itself by translation is a morphism $_:\rightarrow $ (which is only a homomorphism when $ = $ is the neutral element of $$) and the claim that is used by Borel is that the action $_$ extends to the complete curve $\overline{}$ as a morphism $_:\overline{}\rightarrow $, which again is almost never a homomorphism.